# Prolog: missing feature?

Tags: prolog

Any programmer with some experience in Prolog knows the advantages of use unary notation for numbers. By example, if we represent a number as list of 1" ("4" is list "[1,1,1,1]" and so on), we can define:

```
unary_succ(X,[1|X]).
```

the following queries does what is expected:

```
?- X=[1,1],unary_succ(X,Y).
X = [1, 1],
Y = [1, 1, 1].

?- unary_succ(X,Y),X=[1,1].
X = [1, 1],
Y = [1, 1, 1].

?- unary_succ(X,Y),Y=[1,1].
X = [1],
Y = [1, 1].
```

In this way, statement unary_succ(X,Y) "binds" X and Y in a way that, if after the fact is stated, one of these variables is bound to a value, the other one does.

However, this behaviour is not possible if we use the internal number representation:

```
?- X=2,succ(X,Y).
X = 2,
Y = 3.

?- succ(X,Y),X=2.
ERROR: succ/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

?- succ(X,Y),Y=2.
ERROR: succ/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

In my opinion, it will be very useful that previous statements and similar ones does what is expected. That is, we need to link two variables in a way that, when one of them is bound to a value, the other does following the previously established rule.

My questions are:

a) some easy way to do that in Prolog.

b) if not possible, any other programming language that supports this feature?

Any comment is welcome.

Thanks to everybody.

*** Addendum I ***

Another example is:

```
user_id(john,1234).
user_id(tom,5678).
```

and queries:

```
X=john,user_id(X,Y).
user_id(X,Y),X=john
```

that currently are solved by backtracking.

Comment: In SWI Prolog, I think you can do with with clpfd library. You might want to check out its source code to see how it is implemented.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your colaboration. Added to the question another example to clarify.

Comment: I second the CLP(FD) suggestion by @nhahtdh: At least for integers, using CLP(FD) constraints is definitely the relational solution you are looking for, and provided by all major Prolog implementations. Simply write `X #= 2, Y #= X + 1` or equivalently `Y #= X + 1, X #= 2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic is known as [coroutining](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=coroutining), and to be solved in fairly general way - afaik - requires extension to the basic Prolog computation model. Fortunately, most Prologs have such extension... So, let's try [in SWISH](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/coroutining%20intro.pl) to build your own 'reactive' extension:

```
my_succ(X, Y) :- when((nonvar(X);nonvar(Y)), succ(X, Y)).
```

*edit* not completely on point, but Jan posted on SWI-Prolog mailing list a simple example of coroutining application:

```
?- freeze(X, writeln(X)), findall(X, between(1,3,X), Xs).
1
2
3
Xs = [1, 2, 3],
freeze(X, writeln(X)).
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know this statement exists.

Comment: `when/2` exists in SICStus (origin), YAP, and SWI.

Comment: +1 for mentioning coroutining in general. However, this particular example is not very fortunate in my view, because `Y #= X + 1` is more conveniently and much more fittingly solved with CLP(FD) constraints. I suggest you give a didactically more valuable example for `when/2` instead of the current one.

Comment: @false: thanks, effectively when/2 seems not so widely supported. I thought it was be based on freeze/2, but this it's not the case... Otoh  Ciao Prolog offers a library (at least for freeze/2), XSB team motivates the lacking of the construct because of the unclear semantic in presence of tabling, while B-Prolog takes an entirely different path.

Comment: At least, `when/2` is better than `freeze/2` because you can have conditions like `ground/1` and also combine them. See [SICStus' manual](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dwhen.html#mpg_002dref_002dwhen). However, for many purposes it is still a hack comparable to `freeze/2` - think of subsumption testing (which is also the reason for XSB to be cautious).

Comment: @mat: I could not think about a more simple/instructive example, my bad... I thought about attributed variables binding visualization, but it's a lot more complex...

Comment: @CappeliC: How about `my_dif/2`, expressing the semantics of `dif/2` in terms of `when/2`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you describe exists as long as the answers by a Prolog system are restricted to (syntactic) answer substitutions.  In your example, the goal `succ(X, Y)` would require infinitely many answers to describe the entire set of solutions. For this reason, an `instantiation_error` is issued instead.

To address this problem we need to extend answers. So answers not only include answer substitutions but some more elaborate way to describe some sets.

**`library(clpfd)`** offering constraints over Z (and most prominently finite domains).

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
?- Y #= X+1.
X+1#=Y.
```

Note that such solvers are not very strong for the general case:

```
?- Y #= X+1, X #= Y+1.
Y+1#=X,
X+1#=Y.
```

You may expect the system to fail, however it produces an answer which essentially restated the query. At least the answer is not incorrect, for it simply states: yes, there is a solution **provided** this relation holds (which it does not, similar to the fine print in insurance contracts or guarantee certificates).

**`when/2`** is also known as coroutining and is in many cases weaker than what you get with `clpfd`. But, in a few cases it is stronger to some implementations of `clpfd`. Consider `dif/2` which can be expressed as `when(?=(X,Y), X \== Y)` and

```
| ?- dif(X, Y), X = Y.
no
```

... whereas (in SICStus)

```
| ?- X #\= Y, X #= Y.
Y #= X,
Y #\= X,
Y in inf..sup,
X in inf..sup ? ;
no
```

**`library(clpq)`** offers a solver that is stronger in many situations but lacks integer specific constraints like `mod/2`. In many situations it is still interesting to use, as here in SICStus:

```
| ?- use_module(library(clpq)).
yes
| ?- {Y=X+1}.
{X = -1+Y} ?
yes
| ?- {Y=X+1}, {X=Y+1}.
no
```