# leaves in binary tree - to list and from list

Tags: prolog

I am going to implement getting all leaves from tree to list and vice versa - for list of leaves construct tree - I know that such trees is infitity.

```
leaves(nil) --> 
    [].

leaves(t(X, nil, nil)) --> 
    [X].
leaves(t(_, t(Y, L, R), nil)) -->
    leaves(t(Y, L, R)).

leaves(t(_, t(X, LL, LR), t(Y, RL, RR))) -->
    leaves(t(X, LL, LR)),
    leaves(t(Y, RL, RR)).
```

Is seems to be even workin, for example

```
phrase( leaves(  t(6, t(3, 
            t(1, nil, nil), 
            t(5, nil, nil)
        ),           
        t(4, 
            t(2, nil, nil), 
            t(8, 
                t(7, nil, nil), 
                t(9, nil, nil)
            )
        )
    )
    ), X).
X = [1, 5, 2, 7, 9] ;
false.
```

One result, as expected. However, problem is in vice versa - it is looping - of course it is obvious that there are infitely such tree - but I dosen't give any result.

`phrase(leaves(X), [1, 5, 2, 7, 9])` is looping, but for
`phrase(leaves(X), [1])` it seems to be working in expected way:

```
X = t(1, nil, nil) ;
X = t(_G8388509, t(1, nil, nil), nil) ;
X = t(_G8388509, t(_G8388513, t(1, nil, nil), nil), nil)
```

Is it possible to implement it such that it will be working in the same way for one-element list ?

**Edit**

After reexamining your prior answers, I come to following conclusions:

```
leaves(nil, Ls, Ls) --> [].

leaves(t(X, nil, nil), Ls, Ls) -->[X].

leaves(t(_, t(Y, L, R), nil), [_|Ls0], Ls) -->
    leaves(t(Y, L, R), Ls0, Ls).

leaves(t(_, nil, t(Y, L, R)), [_|Ls0], Ls) -->
    leaves(t(Y, L, R), Ls0, Ls).

leaves(t(_, t(X, LL, LR), t(Y, RL, RR)), [_|Ls0], Ls) -->
    leaves(t(X, LL, LR), Ls0, Ls1),
    leaves(t(Y, RL, RR), Ls1, Ls).

phrase(leaves(X, [1,2], _), [1,2]).
X = t(_G1522, t(_G1526, t(1, nil, nil), t(2, nil, nil)), nil) ;
X = t(_G1522, nil, t(_G1526, t(1, nil, nil), t(2, nil, nil))) ;
X = t(_G1522, t(1, nil, nil), t(2, nil, nil)) ;
X = t(_G1522, t(1, nil, nil), t(_G1530, t(2, nil, nil), nil)) ;
X = t(_G1522, t(1, nil, nil), t(_G1530, nil, t(2, nil, nil))) ;
X = t(_G1522, t(_G1526, t(1, nil, nil), nil), t(2, nil, nil)) ;
X = t(_G1522, t(_G1526, nil, t(1, nil, nil)), t(2, nil, nil)) ;
false.
```

I expected infite result, but I got finite result. However, is it incorrect ?

Comment: Maybe you should check out the answers of your older questions? This is similar to what you already asked!

Comment: As an aside, you seem to be missing a rule: `leaves(t(_, nil, t(Y, L, R))) -->
    leaves(t(Y, L, R)).`

Comment: The technique for avoiding the termination issue you've encountered was described in a [prior answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345995/prolog-reconstruct-bst-trees-from-inorder-list#answer-37346279) by @mat, and then reiterated by [an answer I provided later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363525/prolog-bst-tree-to-list#37363779). You should study those answers.

Comment: Both `leaves(nil, Ls, Ls) --> [].`
and
`leaves(t(X, nil, nil), Ls, Ls) -->[X].` do nothing with `Ls`. That don't look right to me...

Comment: Your results are finite because your rules require that a leaf node consist only of elements from your list, and terminates after using each of them once. Which part of that do you want to relax? Use elements from your input more than once, or allow leaves not consisting of one of those elements?

Comment: My aim is to create all trees with leaves from list. Is it clear ?

Comment: Sorry it's not clear. See the questions in my comment. Do you want to use the elements in the list only once? Or can you use each element multiple times as leaves? If multiples, then DCG operating on the list is probably not the right approach since the DCG traverses the list once and is done.

Comment: **1.** For given list:  it should build each tree, where all elements from list are leaves. Leaves should be as many as length of list (no dupliactes of leaves).   **2.** For given tree - it should return exactly one list - leaves from left to right.   Then, These operations are mutually inverse.  What do you think about it  now ?

Comment: From that description I don't know how you would expect an infinite number of trees for a given list since the list is finite, you expect every leaf to be an element from the list, and you don't wish to duplicate any list elements in the tree.

Comment: You always may add new node as root (not leaf). Then you have infinitely many possibilities.  For example, let our list will be `[1]`. Then we may build tree: `1-X-X-X-X-X-X-...` (path, where `1` is only leaf).

Comment: These "leaves" `t(E,nil,nil)` of yours don't make sense to me. Why not store data in inner nodes, too?

Comment: data are store in inner nodes too, but leaf for me is: `t(E, nil, nil)`. It is possible, inner node for example `t(E, t(E2, nil, t(..)), t(..))`